# How to overlay a div on a map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I am currently undergoing a mini web development project of mine and I have ran into a speed bump. At the moment I am using the Google maps API to create a full screen map background to my page. (Refer to code) I am trying to add a div on the top of the map but every time I create a div, when i load the page, i see it for a moment the it disappears? (Im just after an overlaid div with a solid background and a height of 80% and width of 100%)

```
  <style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color:#f6f6f6; }
 #map-canvas { 
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
      }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***********&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeControl: false,
  draggable: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  scrollwheel: false,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: `z-index` higher on maps?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to size the z-index property of your div to a very high value ?

Answer (score 1):

try manipulating your z-indexes of map and div...or better try [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) plugin

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` would do it, but you *could* take advantage of the builtin functionality designed for exactly this, instead of reinventing the wheel. Take a look at [**Map Controls**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlsOverview).

To achieve what you want ("*Im just after an overlaid div with a solid background and a height of 80% and width of 100%*") :

css :

```
  #overlay {
      background-color: white;
      height: 80%;
      width: 100%;   
    }
```

markup :

```html
<div id="overlay"><h2>I am an overlay-div</h2></div>
```

add the overlay to the map

```js
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(
   document.getElementById('overlay')
);
```

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/M6a7q/**