# Show Google Maps top left infowindow on click?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am building a google map and I would like to have some information show when the mouse is over a marker and then more detailed information when the user clicks on the map. I have found a solution for it by adding two infowindows.

**html**

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**css**

```
#map-canvas {        
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

**js**

```
"use strict";

        // variable to hold a map
        var map;

        // variable to hold current active InfoWindow
        var activeInfoWindow ;      

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
        // initialize function      
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
          function initialize() {

            // map options - lots of options available here 
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom : 6,
              draggable: true,
              center : new google.maps.LatLng(43.637599, 1.319152),
              mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            // create map in div called map-canvas using map options defined above
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            // define three Google Map LatLng objects representing geographic points
            var barca           = new google.maps.LatLng(41.387042, 2.181382);
            var toulouse    = new google.maps.LatLng(43.637599, 1.319152);
            var madrid  = new google.maps.LatLng(40.424803, -3.698083);

            // place markers
            fnPlaceMarkers(barca,"Barcelona");
            fnPlaceMarkers(toulouse,"Toulouse");            
            fnPlaceMarkers(madrid,"Madrid");            
          }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
        // create markers on the map
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
        function fnPlaceMarkers(myLocation,myCityName){

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : myLocation
            });

           //var lat_lng = {lat: 17.08672, lng: 78.42444};  

            // Renders the marker on the specified map
            marker.setMap(map); 

            // create an InfoWindow - for mouseover
            var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();     


            // create an InfoWindow -  for mouseclick
            var infoWnd2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                {
                    //pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200,0)
                    //position: {40.424803, -3.698083}
                    //content: contentString
                }
            );

            // -----------------------
            // ON MOUSEOVER
            // -----------------------

            // add content to your InfoWindow
            infoWnd.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' +  myCityName + ' This appears when you put your mouse over a marker</div>');

            // add listener on InfoWindow for mouseover event
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {

                // Close active window if exists - [one might expect this to be default behaviour no?]              
                if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

                // Close info Window on mouseclick if already opened
                infoWnd2.close();

                // Open new InfoWindow for mouseover event
                infoWnd.open(map, marker);

                // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
                activeInfoWindow = infoWnd;             
            });                             

            // on mouseout (moved mouse off marker) make infoWindow disappear
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                infoWnd.close();    
            });

            // --------------------------------
            // ON MARKER CLICK - (Mouse click)
            // --------------------------------

            // add content to InfoWindow for click event 
            infoWnd2.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' +  myCityName + '. <br/> This appears when you click on marker</div>');

            // add listener on InfoWindow for click event
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                //Close active window if exists - [one might expect this to be default behaviour no?]               
                if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

                // Open InfoWindow - on click 
                infoWnd2.open(map, marker);

                // Close "mouseover" infoWindow
                infoWnd.close();

                // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
                activeInfoWindow = infoWnd2;
            });                             

        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
        // initial load
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //       
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

It works well and you can see it here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJLVNB

but I would like to improve this. I saw something that I really like. How can I add an html infowindow in the top left of the google maps like they do on booking.com (img below) on clicking the marker. When you are inside a location you can click on "Show on map" and it will show this feature that I like.

[image]

**How can I create this feature of showing an infowindow on hover and then on click another one always placed at the top left?**

Comment: So based upon your Codepen, you only need to add the static info window in the top left?

Comment: Yes. that's my main problem. Adding html to it shouldn't be hard after that.

Comment: Update: This is not a css issue for me it's a js issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said that your requirement is to place it on `top:0` and `left:0`, there is a method to do that.

You display the content on a `div` with `class=scrollFix`. The entire `div` is it's 4<sup>th</sup> parent.

## add the below code inside the `eventlistener` of `marker -> click` where you generate the info box.

## 1. jQuery

---

```
$(".scrollFix")[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.top="0px";
$(".scrollFix")[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.left="0";
```

## Snippet

```js
"use strict";

  // variable to hold a map
  var map;
  
  // variable to hold current active InfoWindow
  var activeInfoWindow ;  

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  // initialize function  
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    function initialize() {
   
   // map options - lots of options available here 
   var mapOptions = {
     zoom : 6,
     draggable: true,
     center : new google.maps.LatLng(43.637599, 1.319152),
     mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   
   // create map in div called map-canvas using map options defined above
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  
   // define three Google Map LatLng objects representing geographic points
   var barca    = new google.maps.LatLng(41.387042, 2.181382);
   var toulouse  = new google.maps.LatLng(43.637599, 1.319152);
   var madrid  = new google.maps.LatLng(40.424803, -3.698083);

   // place markers
   fnPlaceMarkers(barca,"Barcelona");
   fnPlaceMarkers(toulouse,"Toulouse");   
   fnPlaceMarkers(madrid,"Madrid");   
    }

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  // create markers on the map
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  function fnPlaceMarkers(myLocation,myCityName){
    
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : myLocation
   });
  
           //var lat_lng = {lat: 17.08672, lng: 78.42444};  

   // Renders the marker on the specified map
      
   marker.setMap(map); 

   // create an InfoWindow - for mouseover
   var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  


   // create an InfoWindow -  for mouseclick
   var infoWnd2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    {
     //pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200,0)
     //position: {40.424803, -3.698083}
     //content: contentString
    }
   );
   
   // -----------------------
   // ON MOUSEOVER
   // -----------------------
   
   // add content to your InfoWindow
   infoWnd.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' +  myCityName + ' This appears when you put your mouse over a marker</div>');
   
   // add listener on InfoWindow for mouseover event
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    
    // Close active window if exists - [one might expect this to be default behaviour no?]    
    if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

    // Close info Window on mouseclick if already opened
    infoWnd2.close();
   
    // Open new InfoWindow for mouseover event
    infoWnd.open(map, marker);
    
    // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
    activeInfoWindow = infoWnd;    
   });        
   
   // on mouseout (moved mouse off marker) make infoWindow disappear
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    infoWnd.close(); 
   });
   
   // --------------------------------
   // ON MARKER CLICK - (Mouse click)
   // --------------------------------
   
   // add content to InfoWindow for click event 
   infoWnd2.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' +  myCityName + '. <br/> This appears when you click on marker</div>');
   
   // add listener on InfoWindow for click event
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    
    //Close active window if exists - [one might expect this to be default behaviour no?]    
    if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

    // Open InfoWindow - on click 
    infoWnd2.open(map, marker);
    $(".scrollFix")[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.top="0";
        $(".scrollFix")[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.left="0";
        
    // Close "mouseover" infoWindow
    infoWnd.close();
    
    // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
    activeInfoWindow = infoWnd2;
   });        
   
  }
  
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  // initial load
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //  
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas, #side-bar {        
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

## 2. JavaScript

---

```
document.getElementsByClassName("scrollFix")[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.top="0";
document.getElementsByClassName("scrollFix")[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.left="0";
```

## Snippet

```js
"use strict";

  // variable to hold a map
  var map;
  
  // variable to hold current active InfoWindow
  var activeInfoWindow ;  

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  // initialize function  
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    function initialize() {
   
   // map options - lots of options available here 
   var mapOptions = {
     zoom : 6,
     draggable: true,
     center : new google.maps.LatLng(43.637599, 1.319152),
     mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   
   // create map in div called map-canvas using map options defined above
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  
   // define three Google Map LatLng objects representing geographic points
   var barca    = new google.maps.LatLng(41.387042, 2.181382);
   var toulouse  = new google.maps.LatLng(43.637599, 1.319152);
   var madrid  = new google.maps.LatLng(40.424803, -3.698083);

   // place markers
   fnPlaceMarkers(barca,"Barcelona");
   fnPlaceMarkers(toulouse,"Toulouse");   
   fnPlaceMarkers(madrid,"Madrid");   
    }

  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  // create markers on the map
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  function fnPlaceMarkers(myLocation,myCityName){
    
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : myLocation
   });
  
           //var lat_lng = {lat: 17.08672, lng: 78.42444};  

   // Renders the marker on the specified map
      
   marker.setMap(map); 

   // create an InfoWindow - for mouseover
   var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  


   // create an InfoWindow -  for mouseclick
   var infoWnd2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    {
     //pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200,0)
     //position: {40.424803, -3.698083}
     //content: contentString
    }
   );
   
   // -----------------------
   // ON MOUSEOVER
   // -----------------------
   
   // add content to your InfoWindow
   infoWnd.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' +  myCityName + ' This appears when you put your mouse over a marker</div>');
   
   // add listener on InfoWindow for mouseover event
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    
    // Close active window if exists - [one might expect this to be default behaviour no?]    
    if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

    // Close info Window on mouseclick if already opened
    infoWnd2.close();
   
    // Open new InfoWindow for mouseover event
    infoWnd.open(map, marker);
    
    // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
    activeInfoWindow = infoWnd;    
   });        
   
   // on mouseout (moved mouse off marker) make infoWindow disappear
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    infoWnd.close(); 
   });
   
   // --------------------------------
   // ON MARKER CLICK - (Mouse click)
   // --------------------------------
   
   // add content to InfoWindow for click event 
   infoWnd2.setContent('<div class="scrollFix">' + 'Welcome to ' +  myCityName + '. <br/> This appears when you click on marker</div>');
   
   // add listener on InfoWindow for click event
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    
    //Close active window if exists - [one might expect this to be default behaviour no?]    
    if(activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

    // Open InfoWindow - on click 
    infoWnd2.open(map, marker);
    document.getElementsByClassName("scrollFix")[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.top="0";
        document.getElementsByClassName("scrollFix")[0].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.left="0";
        
    // Close "mouseover" infoWindow
    infoWnd.close();
    
    // Store new open InfoWindow in global variable
    activeInfoWindow = infoWnd2;
   });        
   
  }
  
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
  // initial load
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //  
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 #map-canvas, #side-bar {        
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at CSS cards [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_cards.asp). You can also set the position of this div to `fixed`. I'd suggest you use the meta attribute `viewport` to help it be optimizable for mobile screens.

You can use javascript ot change the visibilty of the card when user clicks on a marker to be visible and to become hidden whenever he clicks elsewhere. Also, the content to the card can be sent from the same js function.

Comment: I was thinking this can be done with infowindows or some other google maps feature and not using an outside div that is updated. I inspected booking.com and they are not using outside div. That being said I'm open to any solution. I will try to use your idea. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to use something that is provided by Google Maps itself?

Comment: Yes. That would be an ideal situation. I thought that's how booking.com is doing it and I don't have the skill to do it so I'm asking for some help from people with more experience than me with google maps api

Comment: I searched quite exhaustively but there doesn't appear to be a car-like div provided by them. Also, I have never seen in in Google Maps. Are you sure booking.com isn't using js to generate a div child or something like that?

Comment: I thought they're using google maps but maybe they are using .js. Is it a better solution to append a child and how are they doing that inside the iframe?

Comment: I don't think anything's wrong if you abide by their Overlays and create a div in it. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181211/how-to-overlay-a-div-on-a-map